# Return nodes related with itself in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, nodes, relationship

How can I get the nodes that are related with any relationship with itself in Neo4j?

It shoud be something like this?:

```
MATCH (n)-[]-(n)
RETURN n
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this instead : `MATCH (n)-->(n) RETURN n`
Without the relationship direction, you will have the result twice.